# Difference Java Random and Kotlin Random

Tags: java, kotlin, random

What is difference between Java `Random` and Kotlin `Random`?
Are they using same algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you dig down deep enough into the implementation of the `kotlin.random.Random` type, you'll find that on Java 7 (if you're using the jdk7 artifact), `Random.Default` will use `java.util.Random` under the hood ([source here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/686bcb830e4045d0c093d98c804f18af059220dd/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/random/PlatformRandom.kt#L53)), while on Java 8, it will use `java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom` ([source here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jdk8/src/kotlin/random/jdk8/PlatformThreadLocalRandom.kt)).

So the implementation is backed by Java's random facilities in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is intended to run on different platforms, and not only on JVM.

`kotlin.random.Random` will resolve to different implementations, depending on your platform (JVM/JS/native).

So KotlinJS won't be using the same algorithm as Java does, and for Kotlin on JVM, it also depends to which of the algorithms you're comparing it to.